# NUnit with .NetCore - Can I write test results to xml or trx file

Tags: unit-testing, .net-core, command-line, nunit

I have a test project (NUnit) developed in .Net Core framework

Below are the references.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="3.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="3.15.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.4.0"/>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I am able to execute the test from command prompt as below

```
dotnet test \Tests.csproj
```

The results are displayed on the screen. However I would like to have the report saved in a xml or trx file.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test#examples You didn't even read the documentation on examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**dotnet test --logger trx**

It is present in MS docs dotnet test